# Create smoother 60fps from 1000 fps source

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a smoother 60fps video from a 1000 fps avi file that I have. I'm trying to use FFmpeg and I'm on Linux (PopOS). I have tried the tblend method to blend the frames but I have seen no difference. I tried minterpolation, but it seems that is used for making lower fps videos higher. I am trying to achieve something similar to [Alfie's 1000 fps osu video](https://youtu.be/hVRdjcuUTks).

Comment: What problem are you seeing in your output video? Is the motion jittery because the frame rate downsampler sometimes has to take the n+16th frame and sometimes has to take the n+17th frame? Are you able to perceive that +/- 1ms jitter? Alfie captured their video at 1740 fps which is a nice integer multiple of 60 fps, so the downsampler can always just take every 29th frame exactly.

Comment: I see ill have to use an integer that also fits better. My main problem is that I can barely perceive the blur. I try to compare the videos and they look the same.

Answer (score 1):

alfie used https://github.com/Wieku/danser-go which generates from osu demo video files that can be of absurd resolution and framerate, it's got it's own frame blending tech

the nearest thing to that and that is compatible with your video file is to use the ffmpeg libavfilter tmix

lets say you wanted 16 samples and to output this to 60 fps, you could use it like so:

```
ffmpeg -i 1000fpsvideo.mp4 -vf tmix=frames=16 -r 60 [encoding args] out.mp4
```

though it'll be way slower than danser since you are applying the filter on every single frame first then dropping 940 of them per second of video rendered, i have yet to find a workaround for this